# Can I run a JUnit test Case as "multiple tests" by different parameters?

Tags: java, junit

```
@RunWith(Theories.class)
public class ExampleTest {

   @Theory
   @Test
   public void isEven(int value)
   {
       assertEquals(value%2,0);
   }
public static @DataPoints int[] values =  valueBuilder();

private static int[] valueBuilder(){
    int[] returnValue= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    return returnValue;
}
}
```

I was able to run a test for different sets of data like from above.

Current Approach:

1. Runs as a single test Case for all 10 items of data. (more like a for loop).
2. One Failure causes the test to stop.

Need:

-> Some approach to run this test as 10 independents tests. Show failed cases as failed and continue running for other data items.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: You are looking for [Parameterized-tests](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Parameterized-tests)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Parameterized Runner Test](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html)

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class ExampleTest {

    @Theory
    @Test
    public void isEven(int value)
    {
       assertEquals(value%2,0);
    }
    public static @DataPoints int[] values =  valueBuilder();

    // Provide data
    @Parameters
    private static int[] valueBuilder(){
        int[] returnValue= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: **`@RunWith` is *not* repeatable.**